# Shared preferences won't save and load data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Here is MainActivity code

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<News>>,
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

private static final String LOG_TAG = NewsActivity.class.getName();

private static final String NEWS_REQUEST_URL =
        "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles;

private static final int NEWS_LOADER_ID = 1;

private NewsAdapter mAdapter;

private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);

    ListView newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    newsListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

    mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(this, new ArrayList<News>());

    newsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });


    newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            News currentNews = mAdapter.getItem(position);


            Uri newsUri = Uri.parse(currentNews.getUrl());


            Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, newsUri);


            startActivity(websiteIntent);
        }
    });


    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();


    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

        LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

        loaderManager.initLoader(NEWS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    } else {

        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
    }

}


public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    if (key.equals(getString(R.string.settings_webtitle_default))) {
        mAdapter.clear();

        mEmptyStateTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(NEWS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String webTitle = sharedPrefs.getString(
            getString(R.string.webtitle),
            getString(R.string.settings_webtitle_key));
    String webImage = sharedPrefs.getString(
            getString( R.string.query_webimage ),
            getString( R.string.settings_webimage_key ));


    Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(NEWS_REQUEST_URL);
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();

    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("format", "json");
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("limit", "10");
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("webtitLe", webTitle);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter( "webimage", webImage);

    return new NewsLoader(this, uriBuilder.toString());

}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> news) {

    View loadingIndicator = findViewById( R.id.loading_indicator );
    loadingIndicator.setVisibility( View.GONE );

    mEmptyStateTextView.setText( R.string.no_news );

    mAdapter.clear();
    mAdapter.addAll(news);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<News>> loader) {

    mAdapter.clear();
}


}
```

Now, sharedpreferences don't work. I want app to store data locally and display it even when there is no Internet connection. I also use NewsAdapter and NewsLoader.

I need help with saving data locally. When there is no Internet connection, I get my own notification "R.string.no_internet_connection", but I would prefer to load news which are already shown before.

Thank You!

Comment: It won't work. You need to write to SharedPreferences in order to save data there. Here is example from docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java
Also I don't think that SharedPreferences are the most suitable option for storing that kind of data. Consider saving it to the database.

Comment: Thank You, I will try it now. :)

Comment: Use [Realm Database](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest) instead of shared preferences.

Comment: Will try; Thank You! :)

Comment: I don't see you are writing anything to sharedPreferences.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yes, I can see now what I have to do. Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with SharedPreferences:

```
 Context pref = null;
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = pref.getSharedPreferences("newsdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString( "savedWebTitle", webTitle );
            editor.putString( "savedWebUrl", webUrl );
            editor.putString( "savedWebImage", webImage );
            editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @zokistone answer ,

There are two ways through which you can write using shared preferences,

1) commit() writes the data synchronously (blocking the thread its called from). It then informs you about the success of the operation.

2) apply() schedules the data to be written asynchronously. It does not inform you about the success of the operation

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = pref.getSharedPreferences("newsdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putString( "savedWebTitle", webTitle );
                    editor.putString( "savedWebUrl", webUrl );
                    editor.putString( "savedWebImage", webImage );

                    editor.apply(); or editor.commit();
```